# How to print the new line after completing the pattern match using awk

Tags: awk

Have the data like below. Paths will be with active ready running state. If not, can ignore those.

```
[root@dev-vm:~]# multipath -ll
dev_mig (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g7) dm-11 PURE,FlashArray
size=5.0T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='queue-length 0' prio=1 status=active
  |- 0:0:3:2 sder 129:48 active ready running
  |- 0:0:2:2 sdep 129:16 active ready running
  |- 1:0:2:2 sdkh 66:336 active ready running
  `- 1:0:3:2 sdkj 66:368 active ready running
dev_mig_temp (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g6) dm-10 PURE,FlashArray
size=6.0T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='queue-length 0' prio=1 status=active
  |- 0:0:2:1 sdeo 129:0  active ready running
  |- 0:0:3:1 sdeq 129:32 active ready running
  |- 1:0:2:1 sdkg 66:320 active ready running
  `- 1:0:3:1 sdki 66:352 active ready running
```

Trying to print in the below format. Getting the output as below.

```
[root@dev-vm:~]# multipath -ll | awk '/PURE/ {print $1 " " $2} /active ready running/ {printf $(NF-4) " "}'
dev_mig (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g7)
sder sdep sdkh sdkj dev_mig_temp (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g6)
sdeo sdeq sdkg sdki [root@dev-vm:~]#
```

But looking to get a new line/shell prompt after printing the entire output. Tried using "\n" multipath -ll | awk '/PURE/ {print $1 " " $2} /active ready running/ {printf $(NF-4) "**\n**"}' but it is not printing as epxected. Please help me to get as below.

Expected output -:

```
    [root@dev-vm:~]# multipath -ll | awk '/PURE/ {print $1 " " $2} /active ready running/ {printf $(NF-4) " "}'
    dev_mig (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g7)
    sder sdep sdkh sdkj 
    dev_mig_temp (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g6)
    sdeo sdeq sdkg sdki 
[root@dev-vm:~]#
```

Comment: for a given device will there always be exactly 4 entries with `active ready running`? will all entries always show `active ready running` or could they show a different status and if so are you looking to ignore other status messages; please update the question with these additional details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's current `awk` code is close; just need to add a couple conditional checks to determine when to terminate a line of `printf` calls; making a few changes to OP's current `awk` code:

```
awk '
/PURE/                 { if (NR>1) print ""                  # terminate previous line?
                         print $1,$2
                         pfx=""                              # reset prefix to empty string
                       }
/active ready running/ { printf "%s%s", pfx, $(NF-4)         # 1st match prints with a prefix of empty string
                         pfx=OFS                             # set prefix to OFS for rest of matches
                       }
END                    { if (pfx==OFS) print "" }            # terminate last line?
'
```

This generates:

```
dev_mig (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g7)
sder sdep sdkh sdkj
dev_mig_temp (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g6)
sdeo sdeq sdkg sdki
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/PURE/ {
    if ( NR>1 ) {
        prt()
    }
    cnt = 0
}
{ buf[++cnt] = $0 }
END { prt() }

function prt(   a,i,rest) {
    split(buf[1],a)
    print a[1], a[2]
    for ( i=4; i<=cnt; i++ ) {
        if ( buf[i] ~ /active ready running/ ) {
            split(buf[i],a)
            rest = (rest == "" ? "" : rest OFS) a[3]
        }
    }
    if ( rest != "" ) {
        print rest
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
dev_mig (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g7)
sder sdep sdkh sdkj
dev_mig_temp (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g6)
sdeo sdeq sdkg sdki
```

Answer (score 0):

I would ameloriate your code following way

```
awk '/PURE/ {print (j++?"\n":"") $1 " " $2} /active ready running/ {printf $(NF-4) " "}'
```

after piping command which output

```
dev_mig (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g7) dm-11 PURE,FlashArray
size=5.0T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='queue-length 0' prio=1 status=active
  |- 0:0:3:2 sder 129:48 active ready running
  |- 0:0:2:2 sdep 129:16 active ready running
  |- 1:0:2:2 sdkh 66:336 active ready running
  `- 1:0:3:2 sdkj 66:368 active ready running
dev_mig_temp (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g6) dm-10 PURE,FlashArray
size=6.0T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='queue-length 0' prio=1 status=active
  |- 0:0:2:1 sdeo 129:0  active ready running
  |- 0:0:3:1 sdeq 129:32 active ready running
  |- 1:0:2:1 sdkg 66:320 active ready running
  `- 1:0:3:1 sdki 66:352 active ready running
```

into it, it will produce

```
dev_mig (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g7)
sder sdep sdkh sdkj 
dev_mig_temp (3624a9370402ea6a5e67a4646002114g6)
sdeo sdeq sdkg sdki
```

Explanation: only change I did make was replacing `{print $1 " " $2}` using `{print (j++?"\n":"") $1 " " $2}` so it will prepend all but first these print using newline. According to your requirement there will be trailing spaces in 2nd and 4th line of output. To get desired output I combined so-called ternary operator condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse with `++` after variable. `j++` value is 0 for 1st execution (then empty string is used) and 1,2,3... for following executions (then newline is used). **Disclaimer**: this solution aims to get desired output with minimal alteration of original code.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Regarding `printf $(NF-4)` - never do `printf $anything` as it'll fail when the input contains printf formatting characters, always do `printf "%s", $anything` instead